# Trouble making it so new User can only see one account and all data associated with it

Tags: account, permissions, user, permission-sets, user-profile

I have a new user that I'm creating and this use should only be allowed to see ONE account and everything associated to that account. Is there any way to filter the permission/profile settings so that this one user can only see that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer would be that if sharing on Accounts is set to private, then the owner of an account could share an Account with that user. That's the only way I know of for you to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a User jsmith@email.com with a profile of 'User Profile'.

1. Make sure that 'User Profile' does not have the 'View All' or 'Modify All' permission on the Account object.
2. Make sure that the default sharing model for internal users on Account is set to Private.
3. Create a public group containing jsmith@email.com.
4. Create a criteria-based sharing rule which shares any Accounts named --Account Name-- with the public group you created in (3).

Once the dust clears and all the sharing has been recalculated, jsmith@email.com should only be able to view one Account.  If they can view any others, then make sure that ownership of those Accounts has been transferred to other users.

Comment: This is correct as well, just cannot go private yet due to current setup.